# driver.getWindowHandles(); not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, window-handles

Here's the code, it should print 3 but it prints only 1.

Don't understand whats not working. (Due to this I also not able to switch to new window. I want to switch to window by index.)

```
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

//open two more tabs        
act.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).perform();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Images")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Images")).click();

// save windows in a set
Set<String> winlist = driver.getWindowHandles();
Thread.sleep(5000);

//print set size --------> wrong, prints only 1
System.out.println(winlist.size());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["switchTo" method not working for switching to tabs in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422716/switchto-method-not-working-for-switching-to-tabs-in-browser)

Answer (score 0):

It does seems like an issue with Firefox driver only. I was able to reproduce with current release of Firefox and Selenium version *2.47.1*. However, I do believe downgrading the Firefox might solve the issue and I haven't tried that. I did try the same code block on Chrome just to make sure the issue is driver related and had expected result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\working\\selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

    //get the original window handles
    String originalHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    //open two more tabs        
    act.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).perform();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Images")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Images")).click();

    // save windows in a set
    Set<String> winlist = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String win:winlist){
        if(!win.equals(originalHandle)){
            driver.switchTo().window(win);
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        }
    }    
    //print set size --------> wrong, prints only 1
    System.out.println(winlist.size());
}
```

> Console Output:
>
> Starting ChromeDriver 2.16.333243
>
> (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961) on port 25687
>
> Only local connections are allowed.
>
> Google Images
>
> Google Images
>
> 3

Answer (score 0):

What helps me to fix this issue:
the problem was in declaration of ChromeDriver: 
change "WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();" to "ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();"

So ChromeDriver creation should look like:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chromedriver.exe");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
```