# Clear Network tab using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, network-tools

I am trying to load a page, and I am automating the process of checking for a POST request after a button is clicked.

In order to do this, I need to clear the Network tab of all previous entries before the button is clicked, otherwise it will not show up on the list for some reason.

Is there a way to do this via logging or some other means in Selenium Java?

[image: Network console]

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/browserup/browserup-proxy

Comment: You could restart the browser, that's one solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to interact with Chrome's dev tools as you intent to. Alhough, if you are interested in obtaining/parse data from the Network tab in Chrome you can do that following their quick tutorial in their website [here](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/browsermob-proxy-selenium-example).

I don't know what is you idea but here I leave you 2 cents.
Perhaps you could access this data and work it elsewhere instead of constant refreshing.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636261/how-to-interact-with-developer-tools-in-chrome-using-selenium-or-any-other-libra) is a similar question to yours.