# Press Ctrl+Shift+c using Selenium webdriver is not working

Tags: java, selenium, action

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com)
```

I want to simulate the process of pressing the `Ctrl+Shift+c` with selenium

I have tried:

```
  1.    actions
            .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
            .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
            .sendKeys("c")
            .build()
            .perform();
```

---

```
  2.    action.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.CONTROL + "c")).perform();
```

There are many answers in StackOverflow,but nothing works

Comment: What are you expecting to copy after only navigating to the page?

Comment: It should open devTools, but not suggest the way with chromeOptions

Comment: Why do you want to simulate `Ctrl+Shift+c` ignoring the `ChromeOptions`? What is your exact usecase?

Comment: The problem is not only on the usage of Ctrl+Shift+c other operations (Ctrl+t, Ctrl+Shift+o and etc.) does not work too

Comment: @NorayrSargsyan What is your usecase? What are you trying to do through `Ctrl+Shift+c` or `Ctrl+Shift+o`?

Comment: are you trying to interact with Dev Tools? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636261/how-to-interact-with-developer-tools-in-chrome-using-selenium-or-any-other-libra

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like `pyautogui` selenium actions do not behave as you are expecting.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','shift', 'c')
```