# Access Chrome Browser Console With Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am having trouble accessing Chrome Browser via Selenium WebDriver.

I have tried using KeyDown and SendKeys, but none of these options opened the Browser's console.

My code does not work:

_SeleniumActions.SendKeys(Keys.Control+ Keys.Shift+"J").Build().Perform();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open Chrome Developer console in Selenium WebDriver using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311191/how-to-open-chrome-developer-console-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: what is the error you get?