# How to open Chrome browser console through Selenium?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

I want to open chrome browser console by pressing keyboard keys `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`j` in selenium webdriver. 
I am able to do this action using *Robot* class but I want this without *Robot* class. I have used the Actions class and Keys class using sendKeys. But I am unable to open browser console.

Is it chrome browser version issue or OS? Why the browser console is not opening using Action class and Keys class. ?

Comment: You cannot do that with `Actions.sendKeys`. As Javadoc states it sends keys to the active element (meaning an an element of the DOM). Ctrl+Shift+J is a hotkey of the browser application. `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Keyboard.sendKeys` seems to handle browser keys but I have never used that feature.

Answer (score 9):

To open chrome browser console you can use the `ChromeOptions` class with **`--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`** argument as follows:

- Test Configuration:

  - Selenium: *Selenium Standalone Server v3.14.0*
  - ChromeDriver: *ChromeDriver 2.46.628402*
  - Chrome: *Google Chrome 72.0.3626.96*
- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

  public class A_Chrome_Browser_Console {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
          options.addArguments("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs");
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Google
  ```
- Browser Console Snapshot:

[image: chrome_browser_console]

> You can find a relevant [python](/questions/tagged/python) based discussion in [Opening inspect (pressing F12) on Chrome via Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365968/opening-inspect-pressing-f12-on-chrome-via-selenium/59369763#59369763)

Comment: Thanks you, Let me try.

Comment: It's not console, it's devtools. How did you get any votes on this?

Comment: @BVengerov Let me know if this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTY7V.png) clears your confusion

Comment: @DebanjanB By default the "Elements" tab is opened, and console is hidden. This you can perfectly see from the screenshot in your answer. If you can click on "console" tab to open the console, nothing prevents you to put a breakpoint in the test and open it with a keystroke - why even bother making changes to the Chrome arguments. BUT if you have only VNC in viewing mode, as I do, then this doesn't help at all.

Comment: @BVengerov Possibly now just for the sake of argument you are deviating from your original counter question. Irrespective of `Elements` tab or `Console` tab being opened there is a definite objective behind opening the _Chrome Browser Console_. If you have a usecase/question feel free to raise a new ticket. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.