# Opening inspect (pressing F12) on Chrome via Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, mobile, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am able to open Chrome via Selenium, but am unable to simulate a key press (specifically F12, since I want to open Inspect and eventually use the mobile browser [Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArOWJ.png)) While I'm able to do it manually i.e, open Chrome and press F12, I want to be able to automate this part using Selenium. My current code looks like this -

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--test-type")
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/chromium"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/amigo/Documents/pet_projects/selenium/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.F12).perform()
```

While the code runs without any errors, I do not see the inspect being opened on the browser. Any suggestions and help appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simulating the key press for F12 resembles to opening the [[image]google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools).

To open the `google-chrome-devtools` i.e. the `chrome-browser-console` you have to use the `ChromeOptions` class to add the argument **`--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`** argument as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/")
  print(driver.title)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  The Selenium Browser Automation Project :: Documentation for Selenium
  ```
- Browser Console Snapshot:

[image: chrome-dev-tools]

> You can find a relevant [java](/questions/tagged/java) based discussion in [How to open Chrome browser console through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589156/how-to-open-chrome-browser-console-through-selenium/54592918#54592918)

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for. Do you know how I can programmatically open/toggle device toolbar to select say iPhone whenever I open? I'm trying to simulate key press of Command + Shift + M, but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: @KRW4 Not sure about that. If you can raise a new question I can have a go at your new usecase.

Comment: Is it possible to get it to the console tab. The Element tab is rather useless for documenting errors. thanks

Comment: @MortenB All the functionalities of _Console_ tab probably would be available programatically in Selenium v4.x

Answer (score 1):

As I can not add a comment, just writing as a new answer for others. Just tried that with latest Chrome Driver (100.0.4896) and Python 3.7 -- following is working as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
home_page_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
driver.get(home_page_url)
```