# How to translate selenium into python?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, bots

[image]

can someone translate this into python code so, for example, I know the first and second line will be

```
driver.get("link im using")
driver.set_window_size(945, 757)
```

I just can't figure out the rest

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent [python](/questions/tagged/python) code for:

[image: SelenCommands]

will be:

```
driver.get("link im using")
driver.set_window_size(945, 757)
driver.switch_to.frame(1)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".tg-join > span").click()
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: isnt that equivalent to `index=1`then `driver.switch_to_frame(index)` if so that didnt work it said it couldnt find the index

Comment: @EslamAli We don't have a visibility either to your usecase or the relevant HTML. This answer is a simple conversion of _Selenoid_ commands for which you have provided an snapshot into equivalent Selenium Python client commands. Nothing much. This should help you to get started. See the references as well. Try out the solution and let me know the status.

Comment: is there a way i can inspect element and look at the frames available in a page or like what frame i am on currently?

Comment: @EslamAli To inspect element and look at the frames available in a page you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365968/opening-inspect-pressing-f12-on-chrome-via-selenium/59369763#59369763), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63034593/chrome-devtools-not-find-elements-not-search/63035359#63035359) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589156/how-to-open-chrome-browser-console-through-selenium/54592918#54592918) discussion.

Answer (score -1):

to select a frame you can use

```
driver.switch_to_frame()
```

to click on an item  you can use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath().click()
```

to switch to a window

```
driver.switch_to_window()
```

Comment: thats what i did for switching the frame but it didnt work i did this                                                     `index=1`then `driver.switch_to_frame(index)` but it didnt work