# How to take print screen of console (F12) with selenium/webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu, headless

i use the command

```
browser.get_screenshot_as_file('google2.png')
```

to take pictures of my headless chrome in ubuntu server.
But the pictures are from the hole page without including the console with the errors. Problem is i am trying to connect linkedin using webscraping knowledge, but it is giving me an error. So i want to see if this error appears in the console, in order to solve it.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but you might find a way by looking at this answer that's close to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026390/142780

Comment: I believe i can open the devtools without a problem. I need to take a print screen of it using selenium

Answer (score 0):

If you import `ActionChains` As well as `Keys`, you should be able to press F12 using the following:

```
actions = ActionChains(browser) 
actions.send_keys(Keys.F12).perform()
```

Let me know how that works for you. Action change can be flaky sometimes but there are a couple of other options we could try if this doesn’t work.