# Multiple window handling

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium JAVA. The code below generates an error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"p_subj_code"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 167 milliseconds.

Here is what my code should do:

- Open an application
- Search for the course
- Click on the course
- click on the copy course link
- opens a new window
- click on the Element(this is a drop down menu) and enter the Value in it.

I am getting the error when it opens a new window and then it is unable to locate the element.

My Java code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Course Outline Editor')]")).click();

//Search the course
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Submit']")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='majr_code_id']")).sendKeys("BMSC");
//Enter values for  course

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='p_crse_numb_low']")).sendKeys("234");

//Enter values for  course
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='p_submit_button']")).click();

//Submits the search
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'BMSC 234')]")).click();

//Brings up the course
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("Window title" + driver.getTitle()); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/a[2]/font")).click();

//Click the link to open a new page
driver.findElement(By.name("p_subj_code")).click(); 

//(Opens a new page)
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='majr_code_id']/option[2]")).click();       
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='p'_crse_numb']")).sendKeys("111");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Find']")).click();
```

Corresponding HTML code:

```
<caption class="captiontext">Find Course to Copy from</caption>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="dedefault"/>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="delabel" width="120" scope="row">Subject Code:</td>
<td class="dedefault" width="100" colspan="3">
<p class="leftaligntext">
<select id="majr_code_id" size="1" name="p_subj_code">
<option value="">Select  </option>
<option value="ACCY">ACCY </option>
```

Comment: If you do those steps manually, on the Developer Console, are you able to get the right workflow?

Comment: first suggestion is always the same: try to wait for your element before clicking on it. i.e. instead of `driver.findElement(By.name("p_subj_code")).click(); ` do `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("p_subj_code"))).click();`

Comment: check the response of driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/a[2]/font")).click(); I doubt if it clicking on the link.

Comment: Element by name `p_subj_code` is in same window or it is in new window???

Comment: @Kiril S Unfortunately your suggestion did not work.Thanks for your effort in looking at it .

Comment: @AlllsWell, It is clicking on driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/a[2]/font")).click()  and opening a new window and then it doesn't recognise the element driver.findElement(By.name("p_subj_code")).click();

Comment: @ Saurabh Gaur , As I said earlier Element by name p_subj_code is in new window even I tried Window Handling This doesn't work  :(

Comment: Thank-you guys for looking at my code , All of your efforts are much appreciated :) , I hope to get a way through with this tricky code.

Comment: Yippee......I manged to find the Element on the child window driver.findElement(By.name("p_subj_code")).click(); But after I execute this steps driver.findElement(By.name("p_subj_code")).click(); 

//(Opens a new page)
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='majr_code_id']/option[2]")).click();       
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='p'_crse_numb']")).sendKeys("111");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Find']")).click(); I could not access another Child Window .....

Comment: I used statement If(!handles.isEmpty()){ for(string windowId:handles){ driver.switchTo().window(windowId);if(driver.getPageSource().contains("dedefault"))//"Description" is the name of the label of your text area { try{ WebElement SubCodeDropDown = driver.findElement(By.name("p_subj_code"));  and after this another new child window will open where I have to select the year and confirm in the pop up window to copy the selected details. can I get any help please? on how to get cursor on another child window from the previous child window and then go to parent window?

Answer (score 1):

Tried this? : [How to handle the new window in Selenium WebDriver using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112209/how-to-handle-the-new-window)