# c# selenium firefox open new tab is not working

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

i try this codes and open mozila firefox the get google.com site but never open new tab
why?

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("Body"));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);
            element.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "t");
        }
    }
}
```

and try this but it has never open new tab!

```
namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
            var action = new Actions(driver);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);
            action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys("t").Perform();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript executor for this :-

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');");



namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


 IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
          js.ExecuteScript("window.open();");
        }
    }
}
```

Refer this link :- [How to handle the new window in Selenium WebDriver using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112209/how-to-handle-the-new-window-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: Please accept my answer so other can get help from it

Comment: now i want go to first tab firefox what should i do?

Comment: Use drive.close() it will close your current tab

Comment: You can use windowhandels concept there

Answer (score 0):

Find `body` and then `send` keys.

```js
static void Main(string[] args) {
  IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
  driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com")
}
```