# Screenshots for selenium script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

How to take screenshots for pop-up window by using selenium. I'm using only Firefox. 
1st I was login web site and replace the address details after that update successful pop-up is came so I want to take screenshots for that one.

I used java language

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  What language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For the pop-up window you'll actually need to switch to a new window/pop-up/iframe that appears and you can do that with [selenium window handling](https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html) you can go through new windows, pop-ups, alerts and all.

You can start learning about the window handling just [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112209/how-to-handle-the-new-window-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Then after you switched to the new window just take the screenshot.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;    
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org/");

/* Here we would have the switching to the new pop-up window (Window handling) code */

File file = ((TakeScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
try{
    FileUtils.copyFile(file, new File(location_for_the_file));
}
catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you are still having problems you can check [java example](https://www.guru99.com/take-screenshot-selenium-webdriver.html) and 
here as a [python example](https://pythonspot.com/selenium-take-screenshot/) .

Comment: I used java language